# Ejercicio numero de ocurrencias siempre me devuelve 0

Tags: c++

No sé cómo hacer este ejercicio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me da que el número de ocurrencias es cero y por más que miro el código no sé por qué. Éste es mi código intentado:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const unsigned TAM1=11;
const unsigned TAM2=4;
typedef unsigned TNumeros[TAM1];
typedef unsigned TPermutacion[TAM2];
typedef bool TTachados[TAM2];

void inicializa(TTachados& tachados){
for(unsigned cont=0;cont<TAM2;cont++){
    tachados[cont]=false;
}
}

bool esta(int num, const TPermutacion& permutacion, const TTachados& tachados){
bool encontrado=false;
int cont=0;
while(cont<TAM2&&!encontrado){
    if(permutacion[cont]==num&&tachados[cont]==false){
        encontrado=true;
    }
    ++cont;
}
return encontrado;
}

bool todosTachados(const TTachados& tachados){
bool loestan=true;
int cont=0;
while(loestan&&cont<TAM2){
    if(tachados[cont]!=true){
        loestan=false;
    }
    ++cont;
}
return loestan;
}

bool esOcurrencia(int pos, const TNumeros& numeros,const TPermutacion& permutacion, TTachados& tachados){
for(int cont=pos;cont<TAM2+pos;cont++){
    if(esta(numeros[cont], permutacion, tachados)){
        tachados[cont-pos]=true;
    }
}
return todosTachados(tachados);
}

unsigned numOcurrencias(const TNumeros& numeros, const TPermutacion& permutacion){
TTachados arrtachados;
int suma=0, cont=0;
inicializa(arrtachados);
while(cont+TAM2<=TAM1){
    if(esOcurrencia(cont, numeros, permutacion, arrtachados)){
        ++suma;
    }
    inicializa(arrtachados);
    ++cont;
}
return suma;
}

void leeNumeros(TNumeros& arrnum){
for(unsigned cont=0;cont<TAM1;cont++){
    cin>>arrnum[cont];
}
}

void leePermutacion(TPermutacion& arrper){
for(unsigned cont=0;cont<TAM2;cont++){
    cin>>arrper[cont];
}
}

int main(){
TNumeros arrnum;
TPermutacion arrper;
cout<<"Introduzca los numeros"<<endl;
leeNumeros(arrnum);
cout<<"Introduzca la permutacion"<<endl;
leePermutacion(arrper);
cout<<"El numero de ocurrencias es de "<<numOcurrencias(arrnum, arrper);
}
```

Comment: Copia el código en la pregunta, los enlaces pueden borrarse y en consecuencia tu pregunta no sería de utilidad a otras personas en el futuro. También, poner un título explicativo haría que tu pregunta recibiese mayor atención, ahora mismo tu pregunta es nefasta.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so].Como dice @PaperBirdMaster, la pregunta tal como está es susceptible de ser cerrada. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y que leas [ask] para aprender a hacer una buena pregunta.

Comment: No has añadido el enunciado.

Comment: No añadas el enunciado como una imagen, no se puede copiapegar el texto de las imágenes ni se puede buscar sobre su texto; y si alguna vez desaparece el servidor que aloja la imagen de tu enunciado, los futuros lectores de tu pregunta no se enterarán de qué has preguntado.

Answer (score 1):

Si analizamos esta función:

```
bool esta(int num, const TPermutacion& permutacion, const TTachados& tachados){
  bool encontrado=false;
  int cont=0;
  while(cont<TAM2&&!encontrado){
    if(permutacion[cont]==num&&tachados[cont]==false){
      encontrado=true;
    }
    ++cont;
  }
  return encontrado;
}
```

Lo que hace es, básicamente, comprobar si un número determinado se encuentra en el array `permutacion` y además verifica que el mismo no ha sido ya utilizado.

En principio todo correcto, pero... ¿Qué sucede cuando hay que tachar el número? Para encontrar la respuesta tenemos que ir a la función que llama a esta primera:

```
bool esOcurrencia(int pos, const TNumeros& numeros,const TPermutacion& permutacion, TTachados& tachados){
  for(int cont=pos;cont<TAM2+pos;cont++){
    if(esta(numeros[cont], permutacion, tachados)){
      tachados[cont-pos]=true;
    }
  }
  return todosTachados(tachados);
}
```

Y aquí es cuando empiezan a aparecer los problemas. Para marcar el número como usado no recurrimos al índice dentro de la permutación sino al índice del array `numeros` ¿Es importante este detalle? Ya lo creo, vamos a verlo con el ejemplo del ejercicio (con un triste depurador también puedes verlo):

```
permutacion: 1 4 1 12
numeros: 12 1 1 4

esOcurrencia(0)
  esta(12)
    permutacion[0] != 12
    permutacion[1] != 12
    permutacion[2] != 12
    perumtacion[3] == 12
  tachados[0] = true
  esta(1)
    permutacion[0] == 1
  tachados[1] = true
  esta(1)
    permutacion[0] == 1, pero tachados[0] == true
    permutacion[1] != 1
    perumtacion[2] == 1
  tachados[2] = true
  esta(4)
    permutacion[0] != 4
    permutacion[1] == 4, pero tachados[1] == true
    permutacion[2] != 4
    permutacion[3] != 4

  conclusion: no hay coincidencia
```

El elemento a *tachar* debería ser dado por la función `esta` y no es el caso... eso hace que el algoritmo falle en la inmensa mayoría de las situaciones.

Tienes un auténtico cacao de funciones... las variables no están declaradas donde deberían ni las actualiza la función que realmente sabe lo que hay que actualizar.

La función `esta` debería lucir, dado tu código, más bien así:

```
bool esta(int num, const TPermutacion& permutacion, TTachados& tachados){
  bool encontrado=false;
  int cont=0;
  while(cont<TAM2&&!encontrado){
    if(permutacion[cont]==num&&tachados[cont]==false){
      tachados[cont] = true;
      encontrado=true;
    }
    ++cont;
  }
  return encontrado;
}
```

Y una posibilidad para la función `esOcurrencia` podría ser

```
bool esOcurrencia(int pos, const TNumeros& numeros,const TPermutacion& permutacion, TTachados& tachados){
  for(int i=0;i<TAM2; i++){
    if (!esta(numeros[i+pos], permutacion, tachados)){
      return false; // si falla un numero no tiene sentido seguir
    }
  }

  //Si todos los numeros estan no hay que comprobar nada,
  //la ocurrencia es real
  return true; 
}
```

Personalmente creo que sustituir `while` por `for` para bucles con rango conocido mejora la legibilidad del código.

Por otro lado, no tiene sentido que la función `esOcurrencia` reciba como parámetro el array `tachados`. Podría (y debería) gestionarlo a nivel interno la propia función, pero ese cambio corre de tu cuenta.

Comment: por fin lo he conseguido.
He hecho lo que me dijiste de no tachar el numero y asi lo he conseguido.
Muchisimas gracias :)

Comment: @anonimo115 si esta respuesta te ayudo a resolver tu problema. Márcala como aceptada pulsando en el ✓ que hay en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.